# foreachでカウントする方法

Tags: c#, asp.net

ControllerからViewにデータを送り、Viewで表示しています。

foreachで回してデータを挿入していますが、この数を数えるのは可能でしょうか。
調べてみて、できそうなのですが以下のような感じでしょうか？
多分、簡単なことなのでしょうがお願いします。

```
<div class="info_table">
    <h2>全体</h2>
    <hr>
    <table>
        <tr class="info_header">
            <th width="15%">日付</th>
            <th width="85%">タイトル</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var a in Model.ZentaiList.Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index }))
        {
            <tr>
                <th class="left" width="15%">@m.TourokuNichizi</th>
                <th class="left" width="85%"><a href="#" class="modal-open" data-target="con1">@m.Title</a></th>
            </tr>
```

追記なんですが、上記を試してみたんですが、@m.TourokuNichiziの方が定義が含まれていません
となり出来ませんでした。何か他にこうしたら件数が分るという方法があれば教えて下さい。

Comment: 可能かどうかは実際に動かしてみればわかるのでは。まずは自分で試してみて、どうしても解決できない場合に質問するのが良いかと思います。なお本文のコードは`m`が未定義のため、`<tr>`の前に`var m = a.Value;`などがないとエラーとなります。

Comment: 実際書いてみたんですが、カウント出来ませんでした。
「<tr>の前にvar m = a.Value;」を入れたのですが、駄目みたいです。
 pgrhoさん、毎回質問に答えていただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreachで走査している間のカウント(インデックス)は、`Model.ZentaiList.Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index }`の`Index`から取得することが出来ます。

Razorから取得、表示する場合は次のコードで実現できます。リストのインデックス番号込みのテーブルを表示するModel,View,Controllerのソースコードをそれぞれ提示します。

Models.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class ZentaiListItem
    {
        public string Title;
        public DateTime TourokuNichizi;
    }

    public class SampleModel
    {
        public List<ZentaiListItem> ZentaiList;
    }
}
```

DefaultController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var models = new SampleModel();
            models.ZentaiList = new List<ZentaiListItem>()
            {
                new ZentaiListItem() { Title = "sample1", TourokuNichizi = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },
                new ZentaiListItem() { Title = "sample2", TourokuNichizi = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) },
                new ZentaiListItem() { Title = "sample3", TourokuNichizi = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) },
            };

            return View(models);
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.SampleModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div class="info_table">
    <h2>全体</h2>
    <hr>
    <table>
        <tr class="info_header">
            <th width="15%">No.</th>
            <th width="15%">日付</th>
            <th width="70%">タイトル</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ZentaiList.Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index }))
        {
            var listItem = item.Value;
            <tr>
                <th>@item.Index</th>
                <th>@listItem.TourokuNichizi</th>
                <th><a href="#" class="modal-open" data-target="con@(item.Index)">@listItem.Title</a></th>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

ファイル名、名前空間などは適宜置き換えて下さい。

こちらを実行すると、下記のような感じに表示されます。
[image: 実行結果]